# Flutter Material Keyboard overlays TextField

Tags: flutter

I am sure that this issue has been resolved but I have not found a workable solution. I have a flutter material application with a hand full of TextFields in a ListView. When i select the the text field at the bottom of the screen the keyboard popups as it should but it covers my TextField. I tried replace ListView with SingleChildScrollView. I tried removing the ListView and just using a Container.

Flutter 0.8.2 • channel beta • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 5ab9e70727 (4 weeks ago) • 2018-09-07 12:33:05 -0700
Engine • revision 58a1894a1c
Tools • Dart 2.1.0-dev.3.1.flutter-760a9690c2

I would appreciate any thoughts or suggestions.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51699793/keyboard-pushes-textfields-off-screen help you?

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer. Two step process make sure that you use a ListView and in the 
     Scaffold( resizeToAvoidBottomPadding : true,. I had it set to false because of the keyboard throwing an out of bounds exception.

Comment: To those coming in 2020: `resizeToAvoidBottomPadding` is deprecated, so use `resizeToAvoidBottomInset` instead