# White Screen Appears When Keyboard Pop Up

Tags: dart, flutter

i am new in flutter. I am having an issue but i am not sure how to debug to solve the issue. I try to build a signin/signup page. But when i try to enter value in the textfield it will just show white screen when softkey appears. Not sure why is this happening. Can you please help to guide me on how to fix this? Thank you in advance.

[image: Before[![After]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tz3yW.png)

main.dart

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'sign_in.dart';
import 'sign_up.dart';
import 'reset_password.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.red,
        accentColor: Colors.redAccent,
      ),
      home: DefaultTabController(
        length: 3,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            bottom: TabBar(
              tabs: [
                Tab(
                  child: Text('Sign In'),
                ),
                Tab(
                  child: Text('Sign Up'),
                ),
                Tab(
                  child: Text('Reset Password'),
                ),
              ], indicatorColor: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
          body: TabBarView(
            children: [
              SignIn(),
              SignUp(),
              ResetPassword(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

sign_in.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SignIn extends StatefulWidget {
  _SignInState createState() => _SignInState();
}

class _SignInState extends State<SignIn> {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: Form(
            child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            TextFormField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Email'),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20.0),
            TextFormField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Password'),
              obscureText: true,
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20.0),
            RaisedButton(
              color: Colors.red,
              child: Text('Sign In',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0, color: Colors.white)),
              onPressed: validateAndSave,
            ),
          ],
        )),
      ),
    );
  }
}

void validateAndSave() {}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you guys are having the same issue please try this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51699793/keyboard-pushes-textfields-off-screen). It works for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code..
remove this way to define ..

```
 void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  home: MyApp(),
));
```

try this way i test now is working.

```
class TestApp extends StatelessWidget{
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
home: TabViewDemo(),
);
}

}
```

then ..

```
 void main() {
 runApp(TestApp());
```

this code..

```
 class TabViewDemo extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
_MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<TabViewDemo> {
// This widget is the root of your application.
 @override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  theme: ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.red,
    accentColor: Colors.redAccent,
  ),
  home: DefaultTabController(
    length: 3,
    child: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        bottom: TabBar(
          tabs: [
            Tab(
              child: Text('Sign In'),
            ),
            Tab(
              child: Text('Sign Up'),
            ),
            Tab(
              child: Text('Reset Password'),
            ),
          ],
          indicatorColor: Colors.white,
        ),
      ),
      body: TabBarView(
        children: [
          SignIn(),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
}
}
```

Comment: Hai. Thank you for the reply. I have changed the main.dart to stateless but still no success. Any more suggestions?

Comment: i will try same code but i don't face any issue. if you need then i give full code..

Comment: What? So when you try to input value in the textformfield, you will not get as pic above? Can you please give me the full code